# Strange UNTITLED Volume appeared

Tags: terminal, macos, partition

Whilst trying to format an SD card through terminal I noticed that a "strange" volume named `UNTITLED` existed in `/Volumes/` as shown below (line 7):

```
sh-3.2# ls -al /Volumes/
total 8
drwxrwxrwt@  5 root  admin   170 Oct  2 14:31 .
drwxr-xr-x  35 root  wheel  1258 Oct  2 13:59 ..
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  admin     1 Oct  2 13:59 Macintosh HD -> /
drwxrwxrwx   0 root  wheel     0 Oct  2 14:31 MobileBackups
d--x--x--x+  3 root  admin   102 Sep 24 13:11 UNTITLED
```

However, when I perform a `diskutil list`, it is nowhere to be found (UUID voluntarily zeroed out in line 12):

```
sh-3.2# diskutil list
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *500.3 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:          Apple_CoreStorage Macintosh HD            499.4 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3
/dev/disk1 (internal, virtual):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD           +499.0 GB   disk1
                                 Logical Volume on disk0s2
                                 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
                                 Unencrypted
```

When I perform a `df -h` it only shows me what is inside `/dev/disk1`, so the information there seems useless in this case.

In order to gain access inside this volume I had do `sudo su` hence the `sh-3.2#`in front of every command results shown here. An `ls -al` gives the following:

```
sh-3.2# ls -al
total 0
d--x--x--x+ 3 root  admin  102 Sep 24 13:11 .
drwxrwxrwt@ 5 root  admin  170 Oct  2 14:31 ..
drwx------+ 3 root  admin  102 Sep 24 13:11 .Spotlight-V100
```

And inside `.Spotlight-V100` there's this:

```
sh-3.2# ls -al
total 16
drwx------+ 3 root  admin   102 Sep 24 13:11 .
d--x--x--x+ 3 root  admin   102 Sep 24 13:11 ..
-rw-------  1 root  admin  4683 Sep 24 13:11 VolumeConfiguration.plist
```

3 questions so far:

- Does anyone else have this Volume?
- How to know what space it occupies?
- Can I reclaim used space (even if very small) as suggested in the response of this [question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/228605/why-did-an-untitled-partition-appear-that-uses-up-half-the-disc-space-and-how)? (in other words: `sudo ls -laOR /Volumes/UNTITLED`)

Comment: Are you sure it's not just a placeholder used as the card is being formatted?

Comment: Yes, Tetsujin. As a matter of fact, the computer has been restarted many times (without any SD card inserted) and this Volume continues to **appear in Terminal** only. **Neither** does it appear in the **GUI** (i.e. Finder) **nor** in **Disk Utility**.